# Xlib get mouse wheel rate

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xorg

Is there a property in X11 that tells how many scroll lines should there be in one scroll wheel event?

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49061/change-scroll-lines-when-use-mouse-wheels)

Comment: Maybe this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49061/change-scroll-lines-when-use-mouse-wheels ?

Comment: X11 provides mechanisms, not policies.

Comment: so X11 is not a good choice for writing GUis then?

Comment: it's not in the pointer properties, but on the widget components that decide what **a line** is.  If you are using a TextWidget, just look in its properties, to see the amount of text scrolled by a wheel movement.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. Some people<sup>[who?]</sup> rationalize the omission as "it's an app preference, not a system preference."